# How to determine what xmlns are required for beans component of my spring-servlet.xml(spring configuration file)?

Tags: spring-mvc, xml-namespaces

Can anyone please tell me how do we determine what namespace is required when we write down spring-servlet.xml from scratch?
For example I have the following spring-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="**default namespace**">
<context:componet-scan base-package="org.example.controller">
</context:componet-scan>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView">
</property>
<property name="prefix">"/WEB-INF/jsp/"
</property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

How to determine what should replace "default namespace"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   ...

</beans>
```

You may need to replace thr 3.0 version in `schemaLocation` with whatever version you're using.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But what I meant was that do we have to remember all through our life what is required in the namespace? I mean it has to be hand written always?? I am new to it so such an idiotic question :)

Comment: @Supriya: Yes.  However, you very rarely need to write one from scratch.  Just copy one from other code, or examples, or documentation, or generate one from your IDE.